# Metabase: Lost everything on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ec2-ami, metabase

I was using Metabase on ElasticBeanstalk and everything was fine. Today I realized that the website was off. I saw that the ec2 instance was with the SEVERE status.Tried to reboot the machine. I don’t know if it was rebooted, but after a while it was Ok, but when I returned to the website, there weren’t any of my Dashboards or Questions. It was as the first time that I opened it. I also realized that Metabase was updated. Is there any way that I could recover my dashboards and questions?

Thank you all.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to get your metabase data back?

Comment: No.... I discovered that you need to create a rds to save your data.